# is there anyway that i could insert products onto single row ? here's my session cart below

Tags: php

```
        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){

            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart']
                [$i]['productid'];
                $q=$_SESSION['cart']
                [$i]['qty'];

                $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                if($q==0) continue;


        ?> <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?=$pname?>">
```

the line above shows the added products onto the cart
 i'd like to convert this field onto single input field before i submit it into sql

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can select and insert in 1 query - its not possible on MySQL. This is called nested queries and is applicable on MsSQL, Oracle etc., but not MySQL - you should first get all data then u can insert in 1 row. You can only select multiples with Union or Join.

Comment: is there any way to convert values inside input fields onto single input field.  sorry im kinda new in php  thanks for the help

Comment: i dont get your point? What you mean convert values in input fields. What is your point. What you exactly want to do. I'll be glad to help if you are to be more specific.

Comment: well you see. i got this input field which displays each product i added onto my cart, <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?=$pname?>"> 
if only i could combine values within this fields i could easily insert it into my sql.  sobs. each product produces its own input field btw.